# Y86-64 Leading Zero in Start Position Address for Stack Setup

Tags: assembly, y86

I have a question about some Y86 code

If we're given that a stack starts at pos .200 I'm trying to understand this one line at the beginning of the yas output for the program (this is the sum program in the Bryant text, p. 368 Ch 4)

```
                            |       Execution begins at address 0 
0x000:                      |       .pos 0 
0x000: 30f40002000000000000 | irmovq stack, %rsp # set up stack pointer
```

I understand that for irmovq it's set up like

```
instruction encoding | 0 | F | rB | Value
```

So if we're setting the stack pointer to address 0x200 why is there a leading zero after the 4? Why isn't it 30f400200... ? I'm guessing it's for alignment but doesn't having that padding change the value of the address?

Comment: I don’t see any leading zeroes. If it were `30f400200...` it would load 0x2000. I guess you’re not realizing the endianness etc of the statement?

Comment: You need to chop it up into bytes, 2 hex digits each. That's `30 F4 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00` and also remember it's little endian. So it's `0x200` all right.

Comment: Ah I forgot about the little endian split by bytes. Thank you for the clarification!